# Probability permutation and combination

Tags: probability

A number consisting of 3 digits is created from the integer set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

$A, B$ and $C$ are defined as follows:

- $A$: The number does not contain the digit 6
- $B$: The number consists of three different digits
- $C$: The number first digit is 3

Find $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C)$.

Comment: Hints: with repeated digits, how many different 3 digit numbers drawing from the set are possible? Then, how many numbers do  not contain the digit 6? Division then gives you the probability.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! What did you try in order to solve the questions, before writing there? (people are glad to help who help themselves...)

Comment: Hint: For A, to create the first digit, there are 5 possibilities ({1..5}); for second digit, 5 possibilities; third digit, 5 possibilities.

Comment: @amWhy ok (plus some random char)

Comment: @mau Hope I didn't sound too harsh. I know you were trying to be helpful, and that's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

$*$ There are $6\cdot 6\cdot 6 = 6^3$ possible 3-digit numbers using the digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.

(1) $P(A):$ Of the $6^3$ possible 3-digit numbers, $5\cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 5^3$ do not contain the digit $6$. Divide: $P(A) = \dfrac {5^3}{6^3} = \dfrac{125}{216}$

(2) $P(B)$: There are $6\cdot 5 \cdot 4$ combinations of the $6^3$ that contain distinct digits. Divide, as in (1), to find $P(B) = \dfrac{6\cdot 5 \cdot 4}{6^3} = \dfrac{5\cdot 4}{6^2} = \dfrac{20}{36} = \dfrac 59$

(3) $P(C)$: Fix the first digit to be three (only 1 option). That gives us $1\cdot 6\cdot 6 = 6^2$ total combinations which begin with the digit $3$. Divide this by the total number $(*)$ of possible combinations of digits: $P(C) = \dfrac{6^2}{6^3} = \dfrac 16$.

Comment: @gadoora Does this make sense?

Comment: Clear writeup +1

Answer (score 0):

**Hints** : you should :

1. Determine how many numbers of you can create if each digit is taken in $\lbrace 1,\ldots,6 \rbrace$. Let $\Omega$ be the set of these numbers.
2. Determine how many elements of $\Omega$ satisfy to $A$, $B$ or $C$.
3. Use $P(A) = \frac{\text{numbers of elements in } \Omega \text{ which satisfy to A}}{\text{number of elements in } \Omega}$... same for $P(B)$ and $P(C)$.